# What exactly happens when you have final values and inner classes in a method?

Tags: java, inner-classes

I have came across many situation where I needed to pass value to an other thread and I founded out that I could do it this way, but I have been wondering how is it working ?

```
public void method() {
    final EventHandler handle = someReference;

    Thread thread = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            handle.onEvent();
        }
    };

    thread.start();
}
```

**Edit:** Just realise my question wasn't exactly pointing toward what I wanted to know. It's more "how" it works rather then "why".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can notice what happens underneath by simply decompiling the inner class. Here is a short example:

After compiling this piece of code:

```
public class Test {

 public void method() {
     final Object handle = new Object();

     Thread thread = new Thread() {
         public void run() {
             handle.toString();
         }
     };

     thread.start();
 }
}
```

you will get `Test.class` for `Test.java` and `Test$1.class` for the inner class in `Test.java`. After decompiling the `Test$1.class` you will see this:

```
class Test$1 extends Thread
{
  final Test this$0;
  private final Object val$handle;

  public void run()
  {
    this.val$handle.toString();
  }
}
```

As you can see instead of `handle` variable there is `this.val$handle`. This means that `handle` is copied as a `val$handle` field to the inner class. And this will work correctly only if the `handle` will never change - which in Java means it must be `final`.

You can also notice that the inner class has a field `this$0` which is a reference to the outer class. This in turn shows how non static inner classes are able to communicate with outer classes.

Answer (score 9):

Here's a longer explanation of HOW it works: http://techtracer.com/2008/04/14/mystery-of-accessibility-in-local-inner-classes/

Answer (score 8):

No method can access local variables of other methods. This includes methods of anonymous classes as the one in your example. That is, the `run` method in the anonymous Thread class, can not access the local variable of `method()`.

Writing `final` in front of the local variable is a way for you as a programmer to let the compiler know that the variable actually can be treated as a value. Since this variable (read value!) will not change, it is "ok" to access it in other methods.

Answer (score 2):

This inner class gets translated to code similar to:

```
class InnerClass extends Thread {
    private EventHandler handle;

    public InnerClass(EventHandler handle) {
        this.handle = handle;
    }

    public void run() {
        handle.onEvent();
    }
}

...

EventHandler handle = someReference;
Thread thread = new InnerClass(handle);
thread.start();
```

Since the inner class actually gets passed a copy of the final variable it can not make any changes to it that would be visible in the outer class. To disallow even trying to make changes to this parameter it is only allowed to acces final variables in inner classes.